# An app with four columns

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-logcat

I tried the following code, but the app crashes when I click to view what's stored in the database.

```
DATABASE_TABLE = "EntriesTable"

String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_STUDENT, KEY_AGE,
            KEY_NUMBER, KEY_CLASS };

    Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("select " + columns + " from " + DATABASE_TABLE , null);


    String result = "";

            int IROW = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int ISTUDENT = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_STUDENT);
    int IAGE = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AGE);
    int INUMBER = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID_NUMBER);
    int ICLASS = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CLASS);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {


result = result + c.getString(IROW) + "   " + c.getString(ISTUDENT) + "  " + " " + c.getString(IAGE) + "  " + " " + c.getString(INUMBER) + "  " + "  " + c.getString(ICLASS)
                    + "\n";
    }

    return result;
```

the LogCat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(336):
Caused by:
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "[Ljava.lang.String;@4053eb90 from EntriesTable": , while compiling: select [Ljava.lang.String;@4053eb90 from EntriesTable
01-04 09:59:06.396: E/AndroidRuntime(336):
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a string array in place of a string.

Change this:

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("select " + columns + " from " + DATABASE_TABLE , null);
```

with this:

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("select " + StringUtils.join(columns, ",") + " from " + DATABASE_TABLE , null);
```

Comment: i have just tried it but am getting StringUtils can not be resolved.

Comment: You must import it: `import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;`

Comment: i just downloaded the apache commons..and imported the StringUtils, the error got solved but the data is still displayed out of column headers

Comment: This is another question. It's just an UI issue. Feel free to post another question about that.